# c++ bool template avoiding if statement

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement, boolean

I'm looking a way to avoid if-statement when I'm dealing with template bool function.
Code below shows a simplification of my situation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<bool var>
void f(){
 std::cout << (var ? "TRUE" : "FALSE") << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    const bool b = (std::string(argv[1]).compare("TRUE") == 0);
    if (b) f<true>();
    else f<false>();
    return 0;   
}
```

I don't want to pass `b` as parameter of function `f()` because, in the real application, I am interested in performance and I need to check the value of `b` in a **critical code section**.
I would like a way to write something like: `f<b>();` 
But doing so, I obtain the following error:
`error: the value of ‘b’ is not usable in a constant expression`

Since in my application I have **4** bool templates, I would like to avoid to list all the combination of those four, like:

```
if(b1 && b2 && b3 && b4) f<true,true,true,true>();
else if (b1 && b2 && b3 && !b4) f<true,true,true,false>();
...
```

**There is a way around? Does exists a shortcut that I can use in some way?**
I tried also to use the if-statement shortcut `f<(b?true:false)>();`,
 but I received the same error shows above.

Comment: If  they are really variable arguments, use the right tool for the job instead of template-parameters.

Comment: argv is known at run-time, b must be known at compile-time, so you're stuck. making b const won't do any good.

Comment: yea ok, but does not exists an elegant way to write it down?

Comment: what's the problem with `f(b)` ?

Comment: Of course the example above is a simplification. In my case, for performance reasons I cannot have the `if (b)` condition inside function `f()`

Comment: ok then use an array of function pointers

Comment: This is doing optimization *wrong*. First, you're trying to use compile-time computation to optimize testing a run-time value. That's not going to work. You need to test that variable *somewhere* in this code. Second, avoiding this hypothetical performance penalty is *not worth* making your code unreadable. Third, stop worrying about it! The optimizer and the branch predictor together are going to do a bang-up job of making sure a runtime-initialized constant won't incur a penalty every time it's tested. If you don't believe me, compile some test cases and see for yourself!

Comment: *"for performance reasons I cannot have the `if (b)` condition inside function `f()`"* - You make it sound like you used a profiler and the profiler identified the conditional as your bottleneck. I'm having a hard time believing either one. I doubt that a conditional - in general - would be a bottleneck, and I doubt that you actually used a profiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you want to do.  You want a lookup table that takes a bunch of on/off flags and runs a specific instantiation of a template...

It's possible but a bit beyond what can just be done in a quick answer.  You'll need some moderate metaprogramming.  Where I'd start is:

1. Implement a metaprogram that creates a set of permutations of n flags.
2. Implement a constexpr function that converts a series of flags into a bitmask.  You'll use it both at runtime and compile-time.
3. Implement a metaprogram that will give you a function pointer to the instantiation based on bool flags.
4. Implement a metaprogram/constexpr function that generates an array of such pointers indexed by the bitmask.
5. Call at runtime with your boolean values.

It will probably take a couple hours to implement but shouldn't be THAT hard.

What your original question seemed to expect was converting a runtime value into a compile-time value and that's simply impossible.  But you can implement a jump table such that you don't have to hand write each permutation yourself.  You should ask yourself though whether it's really worthwhile because the end result is going to be harder to maintain, especially if your team is full of junior devs--which I am assuming at this point you are.  A lot of senior devs run for the hills on seeing this kind of thing too.

Oh, and you're not necessarily going to see any performance improvement at all.  Profile, don't assume.

Comment: *"It's possible but a bit beyond what can just be done in a quick answer."* - Wow. Who came up with the idea, that Stack Overflow were the place to write up some quick, hand-me-the-rep-already answers?

Answer (score 3):

You might want something like:

```
template <bool b1, bool b2, bool b3, bool b4>
void f()
{
    // Your method.
    std::cout << b1 << b2 << b3 << b4 << std::endl;   
}

template <std::size_t...Is>
void call_f_helper(int i, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    using f_t = void();
    f_t* fs[] = {&f<(Is >> 0) & 1, (Is >> 1) & 1, (Is >> 2) & 1, (Is >> 3) & 1>...};

    fs[i]();
}

// The runtime dispather
void call_f(bool b1, bool b2, bool b3, bool b4)
{
    call_f_helper(b1 << 0 | b2 << 1 | b3 << 2 | b4 << 3, std::make_index_sequence<16>());  
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/vAKpUU)